# can't load .htc in mode https

Tags: css, apache, html-components

I used .htc to make rounded corner on IE. it only working with http but it not working in mode https. please help me. Thanks
Here is my code:

```
#main .sidebar .videos .grey-box {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px 0;  
  border-top: 1px solid #000000;
  border-left: 1px solid #000000;
  border-right: 1px solid #6C6C6C;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #6C6C6C;
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  behavior: url(../border-radius.htc);
  background-color: #BBB;
  border: 2px inset;
}
```

Comment: Is the `.htc` file on your server/domain?

Comment: behavior: url(../border-radius.htc)

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: What does a profiler say when it makes the request? *Request aborted* ?

Comment: in IE we can't show request. so I don't know this request loaded or not load.

Comment: but when I go to page used https, layout broken

Comment: @khanh - Please check `https://YOUR_DOMAIN.com/YOUR_PATH/border-radius.htc` is accessible

Comment: @ajreal: yes. I can accessible file border-radius.htc by mode https

Answer (score 1, accepted):

two things to try:

try linking to the htc file using http://yourdomain.com/your-file.htc instead of the relative path.

also try this trick:
http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/